# Exclusion implementation in reversing string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In ViewController - I have two text fields, like text field for text wihch user wants to reverse and text field for exclusions, and result-UILabel which shows the result.

In first text field user typing some text for reverse and result-UILabel shows the result of reversed text.

In the second text field, I want to make an exception for letters which shouldn't be reversed in result-UILabel. They should be untouchable in the word of the reverse at the time of reversing the text from the first field and should remain in their places.

The model function is in another swift file in another class.

---

**Model function:**

```
import Foundation

class ReverseWords {

public func reverse(textField: String) -> String {
    
    if textField.isEmpty {
        return ""
    }
    
    return textField.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        .components(separatedBy: " ")
        .map { String ( $0.reversed() ) }
        .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

**Using model function for first text field in ViewController:**

```
resultLabel.text = reverseWords.reverse(textField:
reverseTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
```

---

**Example:**

First text field (for reverse) print:

```
FogmEistEr
```

Second text field (for exclusions) letters which should be untouchable of reverse, print:

```
E
```

And result label shows:

```
rtsiEmgoEF
```

---

How can I implement this?

How can I call exceptionTextField in model to check his characters inside?
Actually, I don't want to do this between classes, but I would like to look at the solution.

I think it would be better to do it in ViewController, but I got confused…

Have you any ideas, how to implement this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to have some examples of what you want to happen. Ie given this string and these exclusions the output should be …

Comment: You can pass the exceptionTextField text to the function and check in the map if the words contain then simply return the word without reverse else return reverse word.

Comment: **Fogmeister** Of course! :) Done! :)

Comment: **Raja Kishan** I edited the question with an example. Is it a good solution to pass exceptionTextField.text to the model class? :) Your example? :)

Comment: In your example. There is an e which is reversed even though it is in the exclusions field. Should the exclusions only be counted if the entire string matches? Or is it a letter by letter match?

Comment: could you please add 2 - 3 more case examples like with space or without space? Do you want string reverse or words reverse in a string with exclusion ?

Comment: **Fogmeister** Letter wich we print in the exclusion - must be untouchble. Changed example. :) The letters "E" are the fifth letter in the word and before the last... As a result, they remain untouched. :)

Comment: **Raja Kishan** I want to reverse words in string with exclusion like letter in every word of string sentence. :)  We have to take into account that the user can write a whole sentence, not just a single word.

Comment: @Gucci The way to address someone is with their at-sign handle. If you don't, they can't hear you.

Comment: @matt Understood! Thnx! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just make an extension on String:

```
extension String {
    func reversed(omittingCharactersIn characterSet: CharacterSet) -> String {
        var reversed = reversed()
            .filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) == nil }
        let excluded = enumerated()
            .filter { String($0.element).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) != nil }
        for (i, char) in excluded {
            reversed.insert(char, at: reversed.index(reversed.startIndex, offsetBy: i))
        }
        return String(reversed)
    }
}
```

All this is doing is reversing all of the characters right away, but removing any characters that should not be reversed. Then it finds and maintains the indices and characters should not move. Finally, it inserts the characters that should not be reversed back to their original position.

Usage:

```
let text = "FogmEistEr"
let omit = "E"
print(text.reversed(omittingCharactersIn: CharacterSet(charactersIn: omit)))
```

Prints:

```
rtsiEmgoEF
```

Here's how I'd plug it into a viewController assuming the reversal would happen either by a button push or by the text simply changing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var originalTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var exclusionTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var reversedLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        originalTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        exclusionTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        tryReverse()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        tryReverse()
    }

    private func tryReverse() {

        guard let originalText = originalTextField.trimmedTextNilIfEmpty,
              let exclusionText = exclusionTextField.trimmedTextNilIfEmpty else {
            reversedLabel.text = ""
            return
        }

        reversedLabel.text = originalText.components(separatedBy: " ")
            .map {
                $0.reversed(omittingCharactersIn: CharacterSet(charactersIn: exclusionText))
            }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    var trimmedTextNilIfEmpty: String? {
        if let trimmed = text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
            return trimmed.isEmpty ? nil : trimmed
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh God, you break my brain! :))) 
But great! Understandable for me! :) 
Now explain me please, how can I use it in my ViewController between three objects? First - TextField for typing some text; Second - TextField for typing exclutions; Third one - result with reversed text from first textfield with exclutions inside from second textfield. @Rob C

Comment: The model function should check the exclusion field for exceptions and then reverse first textField with exceptions from the second in to resutl-Label? @Rob C

Comment: @Gucci I added some sample view controller code. I hope that helps

Comment: Great solution, I understand your implantation. :) Thank you for helping me and giving me some advices! :) @Rob C

Answer (score 0):

Here you can take reference for logic (It can be optimized). We can pass exclude `reverse` function. Rather than put this logic in the view controller I would suggest keeping the logic in `ReverseWords` class.

```
class ReverseWords {
    
    public func reverse(textField: String, excludeWord: String) -> String {
        
        if textField.isEmpty {
            return ""
        }
        
        return textField.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            .components(separatedBy: " ")
            .map { $0 == excludeWord ? String($0) : reverseWordWithExclude(currentWord: String($0), excludeWord: excludeWord) }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
    
    private func reverseWordWithExclude(currentWord: String, excludeWord: String) -> String {

  // return direct reversed string if the exclude word not contain in string
        if !currentWord.contains(excludeWord) {
            return String(currentWord.reversed())
        }
        
        // Replace whole exception word with single space char which is never included in the current word.
        // Easy to find the current index for a single space or for a char.
        let replaceWord = currentWord.replacingOccurrences(of: excludeWord, with: " ")
        
        var reverseString = ""
        var exceptionIndexes: [Int] = []
        
        // Find the index of exclude word and reverse string without include exclude word
        replaceWord.enumerated().forEach { index, char in
            if char == " " {
                exceptionIndexes.append(index)
            } else {
                reverseString.insert((char), at: reverseString.startIndex)
            }
        }
        
        // Now replace single space with actual exclude word at their position.
        exceptionIndexes.forEach{ index in
            reverseString.insert(contentsOf: excludeWord, at: reverseString.index(reverseString.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
        }
        
        return reverseString
    }
}
```

Comment: As i understand, in this case, we should call string from exceptionTextField from ViewController class to "excludeWord" ..? Right? :)

Comment: yes same like textField.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!! :) I understud your implemention, but cant call an exceptionTextField to Reverse class function -> excludeWord..:(( If I will call func  same like in textField in ViewController, it will be reversed in result-Label like textField...

Comment: can you show your code structure with the view controller class so it can help to find solution @Gucci

Comment: I didnt changed it for now -> resultLabel.text = reverseWords.reverse(textField:
reverseTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)). I tried to call an exceptionTextField to Reverse class function -> excludeWord, to make it exceptional. @Raja Kishan

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: Function is in a model, in another swift file. Calling it in ViewController.

Comment: Yes but at what time are you calling ? on any button click or any other event ?

Comment: I have segmentController with two cases, first for the simple reverse and another with exclusions. And yes, now I use the button for reverse, but for the future I want to leave this button only for clearing all fields. For future, typed text in textField must be reversed to result-Label programmatically without any button.